# Rewrite HyperLinkField.DataNavigateUrlFormatString on the fly

Tags: .net, asp.net, data-binding, sql-server-2008, gridview

I have a `asp:GridView` with a `HyperLinkField`.

It's `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` property is set to `View.aspx?id={0}&isTechnical={1}` and `DataNavigateUrlFields` to `ID,isTechnical`

Where `ID` is primary column `INT` and `isTechnical` - `BIT`, i.e. SQL Server representation of `bool`.

So urls are being displayed like `View.aspx?id=1&isTechnical=1` but I want to replace number with a `true|false`.

How can I do that? Suing `DataBinging` event someway?

`RowDataBound` event unfortunately didn't helped - changing `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` causes event re-raising and therefore - `StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET 4.0 generates `BIT` fields as `True|False` strings